# Getting Overflow Error at running .NET application from VBA with WshShell

Tags: c#, .net, vba, wsh, exit-code

Why am I getting [Error 6: Overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264525%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) at starting my .NET application (QCSearch.exe) with the following code:

```
Private Sub StartQCSearch()
    Dim wsh As WshShell
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    Dim pth As String
    
    Set wsh = New WshShell
    pth = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\QCSearch.exe"
    // Following line is marked, when debugging error 6:
    errorCode = wsh.Run(pth, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
    If errorCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "QCSearch.exe exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
    End If
End Sub
```

The .NET application (written in c#) has a main form, that opens a dialog.
When I confirm this dialog, the error 6 occurs and the .NET application is closed immediately.

It seems as the dialog is returning some exit code that is not assignable by `errorCode`.
But as I said, I checked the exit codes of my .NET application and however, they usually should not be returned by closing any dialog, but by closing the main form?!

Also, after debugging the error, the `errorCode` variable is still assigned with 0.

Thanks for any help in advance.

***Update***:

When .NET application is started from Windows CMD, it also breaks after confirming the dialog. Now, I am really confused. Does anyone know why inner dialog closes the whole application?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, **never ever** forget to do this, if you work with relative paths in your .NET application:

```
wsh.CurrentDirectory = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

Comment: You should mark this as an answer to the question, if that is what you intended. It's OK to mark your own answer to your own question.

Comment: Okay, but I am only allowed to do this in two days.